# What is the relationship between the solutions to the LPs with linear constraints $A x = b$ and $A x = b + \Delta b$?

Tags: linear-programming

Let $x^*$ be the solution of the following LP:

$$
\begin{array}{c l}
\underset {x} {\mathrm{minimize}} & c^{\mathrm{T}} x\\
\mathrm{subject~to}~& A x = b.
\end{array}
$$

Let $\hat{x}^*$ be the solution of

$$
\begin{array}{c l}
\underset {x} {\mathrm{minimize}} & c^{\mathrm{T}} x\\
\mathrm{subject~to}~& A x = b + \Delta b.
\end{array}
$$

What is the relationship between $x^*$ and $\hat{x}^*$? For example:

1. Can we derive $\hat{x}^*$ based on $x^*$ without solving the second LP? or
2. Can we obtain any upper/lower bounds on $c^{\mathrm{T}} \hat{x}^*$?

Comment: HINT : dual variables.

Comment: Question: is $A$ full rank? If so you can simply apply a changement of variables such that defining $z=x-y$ with $Ay=\Delta b$ then solve for $c^T(z+y)$ instead with $y$ fixed. You'd get the same question with a shift, which doesn't affect the minimization.

Comment: $x\ge 0$, right, because you said this is an LP?

Comment: @Omer Thanks very much. Yes, if $A$ has full row rank, $\Delta b$ is in the range space of $A$, and we can translate the solution :-)

Comment: @AlexK Thanks so much for your comments. In the current stage, I only consider a very special case with equality constraints. But I will consider more general cases later.